# Accept an input as a word and not a integer

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm and
I'm new to programming and I made something using input:

```
try:
  name = (input("Enter your name: "))
  print("Hello " + name)

  age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
  print(age)
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid Input")
```

I would like the "name" string to only accept words not numbers
like when I run the program usually it looks like this:

```
Enter your name: "name"
Hello "name"
```

but when I put a number into it:

```
Enter your name: "14"
Hello "14"
```

I would like it to only accept words as an answer and input an error when an integer was put

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has `raise` keyword to help us raise exceptions manually.

We check if the name is a number and raise a `ValueError` if so:

```
try:
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    if name.isdigit():
        raise ValueError
    print("Hello " + name)

    age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
    print(age)
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid Input")
```

On run:

```
Enter your name: 14
Invalid Input
```

Comment: Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) an answer if you think it solves your problem. It will help community at large to recognize the correct solution. This can be done by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. See this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) for reference. Cheers.